# Travel Credit Card To Alliance Partner? Capital One Venture X -> British Airways -> OneWorld -> JAL?

Tags: air-travel, payment-cards, loyalty-programs

I was wondering if anyone has experience transferring points from a travel credit card to a partner of that credit card and then to an airline within that airline's point alliance? Is that something that is possible?

For example if I apply for a Capital One Venture X card they allow transferring points to British Airways Executive Club. British Airways is then a partner of the OneWorld Alliance. Could I then use my British Airways points to purchase a flight on another OneWorld member airline like Japan Airlines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Once you transfer the rewards to BA avios, you can use them just as any other avios. Whether or not JAL open the seats availability for partner reward booking for the flights you want is something to look at, but if they do - source of the avois doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you very much!